# Problem with compiling xepersian in LaTeX

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec, compiling, xepersian

I have a question about `xepersian` package. I'm familiar with LaTeX, but a beginner with `xepersian`. I tried to compile this simple code with TeX Live 2017:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{B Nazanin}
\begin{document}
سلام
\end{document}
```

But I got this error

```
! Fatal Package fontspec Error: The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or
(fontspec)                      LuaTeX.
(fontspec)  
(fontspec)                      You must change your typesetting engine to,
(fontspec)                      e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"instead of
(fontspec)                      "latex" or "pdflatex".
 
Type <return> to continue.
 ...
 
l.45 \msg_fatal:nn {fontspec} {cannot-use-pdftex}
```

I tried all other compilers and even updated `xepersian`, but anytime I received similar errors. Also, I googled my problem a lot, but didn't find my answer. Finally, I removed TeX Live 2017 and installed TeX Live 2020. It didn't change anything at all! I'll be appreciated if someone help me.

Comment: when you installed texlive 2020 several programs were installed including pdflatex and xelatex. You are using pdflatex but you should use xelatex

Comment: An alternative is to use lualatex with `babel` and `\babelprovide[import, main, onchar=ids fonts]{persian}`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried all format which you suggested and others, but I got similar errors. When I changed my editor from WinEdt to bidiTexmaker, the problem solved! However, it is a strange question for me, because even TexLive editor cannot compile it yet!

Comment: WinEdt also gives a similar error for lualatex!